# Get username and domain from windows Active Directory in Java on client side?

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, java-ee-6, struts-1

I have a java web application and want to implement SSO(Single Sign On). basically the scanrio is when user hit the url of application in browser i have to get username and domain name and check that user and domain configure in our database so i can authenticated.

i have tried many solution but couldn't get username and domain on url hit.
here is my development environment.
JDK 1.6
EA server 6.3
Struts 1.2
JSP

please don't mark it as duplicate because i didn't find a solution until. if you have any other solution please post it

Comment: How to mark this if I don't have any idea about what is asked here?

Comment: Get username and domain of what? user? by which attribute is user designated?

Comment: @rkosegi this is not simply getting active directory information how to get this in client side java code is running on server side

Comment: @rkosegi yes ofcourse currently login current of client side

Comment: @T.Malik : You may look at NTLM autheintication, beware that browser setup may needs to be adjusted to pass in NTLM authentication.

Comment: @rkosegi thanks for your suggestion. i am looking into this

Answer (score -1):

One option is this case would be to create a DLL like

`Dim UserName As String
Dim UserDomain As String
UserName   = Environ("USERNAME")
UserDomain = Environ("USERDOMAIN")`

and call that DLL from java. That is very much possible in java.

Comment: This is windows specific and will not work if JVM is running under local system account, and of course, Java knows how to read environment variables. If I would go for windows DLL, I will read user's security context instead. But this has no meaning too, because you don;t want security context of JVM, but identity of remote user access your application.